# How do i add a catch callback to my html in angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, angular2-forms

I am trying to potentially display errors i receive from firebase in my HTML and the minute what i do is catch any error(if there is) when a new user is being created and then attach to a variable.
 I then interpolate (errorMessage) in my html to display the error message, but unfortunately it is not working. Any help please?

**This is my component**

```
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        promise.catch(function(e){
        this.errorMessage =  e.message;

        })
```

**This is My HTML**

```
 <p  class="red">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

Comment: Hey @ibukunoluwa! What is auth? Is your own service or is the auth from the AngularFire service? Why the call should fail anyway? Do you have a success handler? You should post more code to understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: The scope context of this in the promise catch is incorrect here. That is why it is not updating.